# creating z-scores for subset of rows

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and having trouble with some basic code.

I have a dataframe with following columns: condition(factor), user(factor) and sensitivity(int). For each user there are 20 sensitivity items. I need to create a new column with standardized sensitivity score for each user. This way I can compare sensitivity scores across users. I am having trouble writing a loop (or something similar) that can create z-scores for each item per user.

I have 14 unique users (this will increase) with 20 sensitivity items.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example? Do you want the z-score for each user on a given instrument or do you want the z-score for each item compared to the others? In either case, you'll have 20 columns per user. You could combine them in some way but how you would do that would depend on the meaning of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at the `plyr` package.  And unless I'm mistaken, which I often am, `scale` is the function you're looking for.  If your data is in a `data.frame` df:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(user), function(x){x$scaled.sensitivity = scale(x$sensitivity)
                               return(x)})
```

Comment: Hi, I just posted my problem below. Same issue, I get lots of NaNs

Comment: @user1229433 You should go back to the source of your data and find out why the columns that you expect to be numeric aren't.  you should only get `NaN` if you're trying to scale a vector of all the same numbers (i.e. the standard deviation is zero).

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop in this case. Use vectorization, instead. Let's consider the following simulated data: (not sure it will reproduce exactly your dataset, but hopefully you'll get the general idea)

```
dfrm <- data.frame(cond=gl(2, 1, 100, labels=LETTERS[1:2]), 
                   user=gl(50, 2, labels=paste("id", 1:20, sep="")), 
                   sensitivity=runif(100, 1, 5))
```

Computing z-scores is as simple as

```
dfrm$z.sensitivity <- scale(dfrm$sensitivity)
```

If you want z-scores conditional on `cond`, then you can do either

```
with(dfrm, tapply(sensitivity, cond, scale))
```

or, using [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html),

```
ddply(dfrm, c("cond"), transform, sensitivity.z = scale(sensitivity))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. 
This works but it gives grand z-score (for all users combined) dfrm$z.sensitivity <- scale(as.numeric(dfrm$sensitivity))
but when I try:
ddply(toolchoice, .(user), transform, sensitivity.z = scale(as.numeric(sensitivity)))
I get lots of NaNs in the column. I had to do as.numeric as for some reason its not reading it as integer.